# How to trigger another Jenkins build if current not finished

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins build that for the first part will launch a webserver on localhost, the build gets to a point where the application is served:

```
Running "connect:server_jenkins" (connect) task
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://localhost:3000
```

My problem here is that after this I can't do anything else can I, no other shell commands will run until this process has an exit code I believe. I would even happily trigger another build at this point.

The purpose of this is that the application gets setup and then I have functional tests (Cucumber) that run.

How can I approach this?

Comment: What if you spawn a new asynchronous process for the web server launch?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Spawning a new process asynchronously depends on your OS/Shell:

#### Windows

[MS TechNet, Command-Line Reference, Start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> Starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command.

#### Bash

[Bash Reference Manual, 3.2.5 Coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses):

> A `coprocess` is a shell command preceded by the `coproc` reserved word. A coprocess is executed asynchronously in a subshell, as if the command had been terminated with the `'&'` control operator, ...

See also [How do you use the command coproc in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270/88374) with its great accepted answer.

To prevent Jenkins to kill all processes on job finish see [Use Jenkins >
ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller):

> To reliably kill processes spawned by a job during a build, Jenkins contains a bit of native code to list up such processes and kill them.
>
> ...
>
> **If your build wants to leave a daemon running behind...**
>
> ... change the environment variable BUILD_ID which Jenkins's ProcessTreeKiller is looking for. This will cause Jenkins to assume that your daemon is not spawned by the Jenkins build.
>
> ```
> BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
> ```

I tried the following in a ***Build*** step → ***Execute Windows batch command*** → *Command*:

```
start ..\..\jobs\<job's name>\endless.cmd
```

(Relative path depending on *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → <kbd>**Advanced...**</kbd> → *Workspace Root Directory*, I use `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`)

with `endless.cmd` containing:

```
set BUILD_ID=dontKillMe

ping -t localhost
```

and it worked:

- the build finished successfully
- two processes, `cmd.exe` and `ping.exe`, keep running

Since your build continues immediately after spawning the asynchronous process you most probably have to wait for a certain time, or check for a file existing etc., before you really continue.

Comment: thank you for the in depth answer, Im running jenkins on a mac mini, so ill have a look and see if i can get this working